# How to save a selected radio button in db in django

Tags: django, multiple-choice

I am creating a multiple choice quiz and I am not able to save the selected option on the radio button in the database as a new answer. Also, I want you to show if the option matches the correct answer.
When I select one of the options, it appears in the address bar the value of the radio button next to the text, but I want this value to be saved in db.

views.py

```
def detalhes(request, idProva):
    prova = get_object_or_404(Prova,pk=idProva)
    model = Prova
    template_name = 'polls/detalhes.html'  # Default: <app_label>/<model_name>_list.html
    context_object_name = 'prova'  # Default: object_list
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Prova.objects.all()
    usuario = request.user.id
    questao = request.POST.get('idQuestao')
    try:
        questao_selec = prova.questao_set.get(pk=request.POST['questao'])
        pagina = paginator.page(page)
        resposta = Resposta(resposta=resposta,idQuestao=idQuestao,idResposta=1,respostacerta=1)
        resposta.save()
        return redirect('/')
    except (KeyError,Questao.DoesNotExist):
        return render (request,'polls/detalhes.html',{
            'prova': prova,
        })
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    else:
        #questao_selec.votes += 1
        questao_selec = Questao(textoQuestao=request.POST.get('textoQuestao'),imagemQuestao=request.FILES('imagemQuestao'),imagem2Questao=request.FILES('imagem2Questao'),perguntaQuestao=request.POST.get('perguntaQuestao'))
        resposta_selec = Resposta(idResposta = request.POST.get('idResposta'),idQuestao = request.POST.get('idQuestao'),usuario = request.POST.get('usuario'),resposta = request.POST.get('#mysubmit'))
        questao_selec.save()
        resposta_selec.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:resultados',args=(prova.idProva,)))
```

detalhes.html

```
<form id="NPSform" method="GET">
                {% if not resposta.usuario %}
                 <input type="radio" name="scores" id="A" value="A"> A) {{questao.aOpcao}}<br>
                 <input type="radio" name="scores" id="B" value="B"> B) {{questao.bOpcao}}<br>
                 <input type="radio" name="scores" id="C" value="C"> C) {{questao.cOpcao}}<br>
                 <input type="radio" name="scores" id="D" value="D"> D) {{questao.dOpcao}}<br>
                 <input type="radio" name="scores" id="E" value="E"> E) {{questao.eOpcao}}<br>
                 <input type="submit" style="display: none;" name="mysubmit" value='{{resposta.resposta}}'>
                 <button id="btnresposta" class="btn btn-primary" >Selecionar resposta</button>
                {% else %}
                 {{ resposta.resposta }}
                {% endif %}
              </form>
```

models.py

```
class Questao(models.Model):
    idQuestao = models.CharField(max_length=7,primary_key=True,null=False)
    idProva = models.ForeignKey(Prova,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idCategoria = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria,default="Categorias")
    textoQuestao = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)
    imagemQuestao = models.FileField(upload_to='static/img/uploads',blank=True,null=True)
    imagem2Questao = models.FileField(upload_to='static/img/uploads',blank=True,null=True)
    perguntaQuestao = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    aOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True)
    bOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True)
    cOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True)
    dOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True)
    eOpcao = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=True)
    respostaQuestao = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    STATUS_QUESTAO_CHOICES = (
        (UM,'Ativa'),
        (DOIS,'Inativa'),
    )
    statusQuestao = models.IntegerField('Status de questão',choices=STATUS_QUESTAO_CHOICES,null=False)
    QUESTAO_CHOICES = (
        (UM,'Múltipla escolha'),
        (DOIS,'Discursiva'),
    )
    tipoQuestao = models.IntegerField('Tipo de questão',choices=QUESTAO_CHOICES,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.idQuestao
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Questão"
            verbose_name_plural = "Questões"

class Resposta(models.Model):
    idResposta = models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True,null=False)
    idQuestao = models.ForeignKey(Questao,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resposta = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    certaresposta = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.idResposta
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `request.POST` in your view, but you have `method=GET` in your form.